# How can iget my Dell PC to recognize the Ubuntu live cd?

Tags: live-cd

I am new to Ubuntu, I have an old Dell PC which uses XP. With the end of support I looked at alternatives and bought a live CD of Puppy Slacko 5.7, which I liked, but I wanted something a bit more powerful, so I purchased a live installation CD of Ubuntu 14.04.2 (32-bit) with the intention of deleting Windows and replacing it with Ubuntu. However when I try to reboot, the disc is ignored, and just boots to Windows ( the boot sequence is correct as if I switch to the Puppy CD, it boots to that immediately. I tried running Windows and accessing the CD from there, but when I click on CD device to open it, it says 'INSERT MEDIA' as if no disc was there.
Any help would be appreciated as what I thought would be a straight forward process, has become a real pain in the a**e, as I didn't want to get into partitioning the drives, as my PC skills are limited.
Thanks.

Comment: To me it seems that for some reason your CD drive cannot read the Ubuntu CD. You could try to burn a new installation CD by yourself in Windows.

Comment: BTW...are you sure it's a CD, not a DVD? If I remember correctly, Ubuntu 14.04 is too large to fit in a CD.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu disk is probably a DVD. Older computers can't play DVD's.You can try to burn a CD yourself:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Or install it on a usb drive

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows